# Import inital data from realm database file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have exported realm database file (.realm) includes initial data for my app. I have use it for my Android app and I willing to use that initial database for my iOS app too. Can anyone help me how to import and use exported realm db file inside my iOS project using Swift in proper way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put your exported realm file in the Bundle Resources

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
        fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: "realm"),
        readOnly: true)

let realm = try? Realm(configuration: config)
```

The realm file has to be read only.